# How to display link from MySQL DB table in react native

Tags: mysql, json, react-native

I am trying to fetch data from MySql database in react native. For that I converted the MySql database table into json, with that I am fetching data. But there is a field in my MySQL table which contains url or links.I have fetched all the text data. 
Now I am having a problem in fetching links from json file.

Just like in PHP, we fetch it like that

`<button onclick="window.open('<?php echo $row["url"]; ?>')" >Website</button>`

But I don't know how to fetch links from json file.
I tried to do this -

```
<Button onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('rowData.url') }} > //here url is a field name
    Website
 </Button>
```

But, it is not working.

Comment: I cant understand what you said! Please use states and then pass it to openURL function to open webpage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import rowData from './test.json'
//...
//...
<Button onPress={() => { Linking.openURL(rowData.url) }} > //here url is a field name
    <Text> Website </Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: I have updated my question..hope you will understand now

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the contents of the file into a JSON object first, then you can get the url property. Without knowing too much about the code it should look something like this.

```
onPress={() => { JSON.parse(Linking.openURL('rowData')).url }}
```